# New router directs inbound requests to own WAN address to the settings page

Tags: router, firewall, port-forwarding

I just replaced my old DLINK router with a Cisco RV180 (and a new zyxel nwa3560-n as AP). I have forwarded ports 80 and 22(ssh) to my servers local ip.

When I use my phone over 3G network, it is no problem to connect to either server over http and ssh on the external IP. But when I try to connect to the server over wifi using the external IP, as I always did when the DLINK was the router, I get the router settings page.

This is not desired behaviour, as some employees use a website which then points to our external IP (the http service). They need to be able to do this both from this site and from other places.

How can I configure the router so it will not forward to the router settings page when the external IP is used from the inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't. You will need to set up the internal DNS servers to override the A record for the appropriate hostnames.